# My form won't Submit - is this because I have a Div in the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a form which has a select input at the top, and when 2 of 3 options are selected the rest of the form appears to be filled in. This works, however the back and submit buttons don't work now. I can't figure out why this is, I am thinking that it might have something to do with not being allowed to have DIVs within a form, but I always thought you could?

My Code is below, any advice on how to get the submit and back button to work??

```
<div class="form">

        Does the Claimant have a PAB/CAB? <br><br>
         <select id="PABandCAB" required onchange="showDiv(this)">
         <option value="select" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
         <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
         <option value="Confirmed">Potential</option>
         <option value="NotRequired">Not Required</option>
        </select> <br><br><br> 

   <form action="InternalRef4.html">
<div id="hidden_div">
    <hr> <br>
    Title: 
    <select name="title"required>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    </select>   <br><br>
    First Name: 
    <input type="text" name="fname"required><br> <br>
    Surname: 
    <input type="text" name="sname"required><br> <br>
    Address: 
    <select name="Address"required>
        <option value="Same">Same As Claimant</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select><br> <br>
    Representative Address Line 1: 
    <input type="text" name="HALine1"><br> <br>
    Representative Address Line 2: 
    <input type="text" name="HALine2"><br> <br>
    Representative Address Town/City: 
    <input type="text" name="HATownorCity"><br> <br>
    Representative Address County: 
    <input type="text" name="HACounty"><br> <br>
    Representative Address Post Code: 
    <input type="text" name="HAPostCode"><br> <br>
    National Insurance Number: 
    <input type="text" name="NINO"><br><br>
    Date of Birth: 
    <input type="date" name="DOB"><br><br>
    Contact Number - Home: 
    <input type="text" name="ContactNumHome"><br> <br>
    Contact Number - Mobile:
    <input type="text" name="ContactNumMobile"><br> <br>
    Contact Number - Other: 
    <input type="text" name="ContactNumOther"><br> <br>
    Unacceptable Customer Behaviour (UCB): <br>
    No <input type="radio" name="UCBNO" value="No" checked><br>
    Yes <input type="radio" name="UCBYes" value="Yes"><br> <br>

</div>
    <a href="InternalRef2.html"><input type="button" value="Back"/></a>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



</div>

<script>
   var select = document.getElementById('PABandCAB'),
   onChange = function(event) {
   var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "Confirmed";

   document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = shown ? 'block' : 'none';
};



 if (window.addEventListener) {
 select.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
 } else {
   select.attachEvent('onchange', function() {
   onChange.apply(select, arguments);
 });
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page?

Comment: Did you define "showDiv"?

Comment: Just copied and pasted this code to JSFiddle and it seemed to submit to the other page (of course this came up with an error as it didn't exist) but still https://jsfiddle.net/nnnb22yt/

Comment: Div inside form does not create a problem.

Comment: I have just tried that link and i found that the back button works but the submit button doesn't? So there is just a problem with the submit i think?

Comment: @DanielCasserly The submit button now works when the form is completed (so for confirmed and potential) just not for 'Not Required'?